# vscode launch npm script throws ENOENT error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to run an npm script from within vscode, and in my `launch.json` I have the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "dev"
            ],
            "port": 5858
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

Then in my `package.json` I am doing this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "hot-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --max_old_space_size=2096 -r babel-register server.js",
    "dev": "npm run hot-server -- --start-hot",
  }
}
```

When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> I get the following error:

> Cannot launch debug target (spawn npm ENOENT).

Am I doing something wrong in my launch file?

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you using? Windows?

If so, you'll need to edit the `runtimeExecutable` and add "`.cmd`" (to instead target the Windows variant of the npm executable.)

As in...

> "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd",

I was having the same problem and it fixed it for me.

Here is a [corroborating source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2726#issuecomment-267433629) I found for this technique (there are various mentions of the issue spread around the net, few that list this as a specific fix for the specific error message we both received.)

The error message I was receiving (Google fodder, in case it helps anyone else)

> Node process error: Error: spawn npm ENOENT

Without this fix, it is trying to launch (literally) a file in the same location named only `npm` (which is the *nix/Mac variant, rather than a valid windows executable, instead.)